# Highlight cell values using navigation buttons with Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want my code to be able to select a cell value from table and highlight it on pressing  up, down, left and right four buttons present over the web page.

Comment: You will likely need to improve the quality of this question in order to get helpful answers. [Here is advice from Jon Skeet how to write a good question](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints). My summary: 1. State your objective. 2. Describe what you expect to see. 3. Describe what you actually see. 4. List detailed steps how to recreate the problem. 5. Show your code in a live working demo. I recommend jsBin but others will work too like CodePen, jsFiddle, Plunkr, etc. Feel free to click on my profile and look at some questions I've written that follow this pattern.

Comment: I'm not the best question writer in the world. But I've been happy with the results I've gotten; and I've written a lot of questions so the latter ones have been molded by my experience of what works on this site. Jon Skeet, by contrast, is one of if not the top user of this site (by reputation) so give his words a lot of weight.